# Windows Causing Issues

Tags: windows-10

I am not sure what the culprit is, but it started after I upgraded my pc components and re-installed windows. I am having issues where windows becomes unresponsive for a few seconds when attempting to access drives including saving/opening documents.

As an example.

I use sublime text quite a bit to do development stuff. Whenever I make a new file then attempt to save it, or even open an existing file, the application freezes for a second or two before the file browser window opens up. It doesn't do it all the time, but it does it more often than not.

If I click on the 'cancel' button to cancel saving/opening,the application then locks up for a second and makes it impossible to do anything until it responds again.

It does this for ALL applications, not just Sublime, just using Sublime as an example of one of the problems.

Also, when I make a new folder in any directory, most of the time I need to press F5 in order to be able to even name the folder, as it doesn't show up until I do. After I rename it, I have to refresh again for the folder/file rename to show up.

Also, when I press the windows key and attempt type in, for example, C:\Test\ to navigate to a folder, most of the time, the autocomplete stops working, and I can't access the folder. I then have to press the windows button again and begin typing again to navigate to the folder.

It does it across all plugged in drives I have, and they are all SSD drives and all new within the last 4-5 months. Diagnostics tools don't report any issues with them.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser. This question is a bit ... lacking. Especially the part where you explain what you have tried. You write that you replaced parts in your PC. Did you verify that all extension cards are properly seated in their slots? Screws have been tightened again? Have you at all tampered with the CPU heatsink? Have you perhaps removed it but then re-seated it without also replacing the heat-conducting paste/pads? Have you looked in the event viewer (`eventvwr.exe`)? What errors are being shown? Which coincide with the issues you encounter? Crashes? PerfMon? ...

Comment: Also, do you have any anti-malware installed? Perhaps multiple products? Provided it's a recent enough Windows release (recent enough to only support mini-FSFDs) call `fltmc` as privileged user and paste the output into your question when editing in the other information ...

Comment: So for clarity, when I said I upgraded my components, I meant everything. Motherboard, ram, processor, hard drives, graphics card, the whole thing. The only piece of hardware I originally had is my case.

It's been an issue ever since I got everything re-installed. Games, other applications, everything run fine, its ONLY a problem when trying to access windows interfaces like the file manager or start menu.